# Honeypot PHP for Comment Form

Tags: php, forms, validation, comments, honeypot

I am creating a jquery ajax popup comment form, but am having a problem with the way Im setting up my "honeypot" in php.

The honeypot ($robotest) isn't working; instead the script returns "E-mail is not correct". Can anyone point out my error? Thank you

The html form is:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="">
   <p>
     <label for="cname">Name</label>
     <input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="cemail">E-Mail</label>
     <input id="cemail" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="curl">URL</label>
     <input id="curl" name="url" size="25"  class="url" value="" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="ccomment">Your comment</label>
     <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" cols="22"  class="required"></textarea>
   </p>
    <p class="robotic" id="pot">
        <label>Please leave this blank:</label>
        <input name="robotest" type="text" id="robotest" class="robotest" />
    </p>
   <p>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </p>
```

EDIT:

Thanks to @JamWaffles for the support. Below is the correct way to implement the honeypot. (And as Kamalo noted you will want to have the id of 'robotest' set to display:none in your css):

```
<?php
$robotest = $_POST['robotest'];
$email = $_POST['email'];   
if((!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && ($robotest == "")) { 
    print "E-mail is correct";      
    $to      = 'asdfdsafasdfsda@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com';       
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);        
} else {
    print "E-mail is not correct";
}   
?>
```

Comment: Trace your logic... `var_dump` each condition separately to trace your code and find the problem

Comment: The problem is with the honeypot ($robotest). Adding the && ($robotest = "") causes the script to return email not correct. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) returns a non-falsy value when the email is valid, not `false`. Remove the `!` before `filter_var(` in  your `if()`:

```
if((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && ($robotest = ""))
```

You're executing code inside the `if()` when `filter_var()` *fails*, which is why you're getting

> E-mail is not correct

for valid emails.

---

Something else I missed too is the fact you're *assigning to* `$robotest` instead of comparing it against an empty string. You need to use the double equals comparison operator instead of the single equals assignment operator. Your `if()` should look like this:

```
if((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && ($robotest == ""))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Guess i didn't fully understand filter_var(). Removed the ! from the if statement, but for some reason it still returns "Email is not correct." Anything else that I could be missing?

Comment: Thanks @JamWaffles. I changed the operator to a double equal but still  for some reason it doesn't work. I edited the above php so that it is current.

Comment: You still have the `!` before `filter_var()`. Have you taken that out in your actual code? Because it's still there in your edited post.

Comment: It validates correctly with the !. It validates incorrectly without the !. I cant understand why?

Comment: `if(!filter_var())` means "if `filter_var()` returns a _non true_ (i.e. false) value, execute whatever's inside the `if()`". The `!` inverts the boolean value of `filter_var()`, so when it returns `false`, the `if()` 'sees' it as returning `true`, so the if can execute.

Answer (score 4):

For an alternative answer, I set up a "honey pot" input in my html with display:none

```
<input type="text" name="honeypot" id="honeypot" style="display:none;"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. The css for my honeypot is set to display:none, as well.